# Prevent combobox popup when user is typing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

Is it possible to prevent a kendo combobox from opening it's popup when the user is typing text?  I still want allow the user to click on the arrow button.  The `open` event can prevent the popup from opening but there's no way to know what triggered the event.

```
$("#customers").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "ContactName",
    dataValueField: "CustomerID",
    //delay: 999999,  WORKAROUND #1
    //enforceMinLength: true,  WORKAROUND #2
    //minLength: 999999,  WORKAROUND #2
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "..."
        }
    },
    open: function (e) {
      //Triggered by user click or by user input?
      if (triggeredByUserInput) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
})
```

The only workarounds I've found so far is to set a very long `delay` or to enforce the `minLength` with a long length.  While they both work, I think it's a very odd way to fix the problem in the first place so I was wondering if there was a more specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open event still provides a reference to the original event, so you can check if the user clicked on the arrow button or not - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/Uxalaleg):

```
open:function(e) {
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass("k-button-icon")){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

or even

```
open:function(e) {
    if(!(event.type == "click")){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't even know about the event object.  That can be very handy to handle many kendo widget.